# How to display dynamically created span id

Tags: php, jquery

```
<table>
<?php 
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
{
?>
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" class="form-control changesNo" id="id_<?php echo $i;?>" name="quantity" value="" ></td>
  <td><span id="sp_<?php echo $i;?>">200</span></td>
  <td><span id="tt_<?php echo $i;?>"></span></td></tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
<span id="gotal"></span>
```

Here is 10 rows created. To enter a number in text box, the same time text box value and span value **eg:  (rslt = #id_1 * #sp_1)**  and display its result on **#tt_1**. and the sum of **#tt_1** is displayed in **#gotal**
**Help me please**

Comment: If you're asking how to do this in php, you can't, because php can't evaluate the value in an element.  This is because the element hasn't been rendered yet when php is executing.  If you're asking something else, you'll need to explain what you're trying to do more clearly.

Comment: You tagged `jquery`, that is what you would use; or javascript. Have you some jquery/js code you are having issues with?

Comment: in jquery how to get span id in jquery when textbox onblur
Itry this 
`$(document).on('change keyup blur','.changesNo',function(){
 var id = $('span[id^="span"]').attr("id");
 alert(id);`

Comment: but the alert message is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to calculate the sums every time the inputs change their values:

- The event handler for input changes is

  $('input.form-control.changesNo').on('input'....
- Because each group of elements of your interest has the same suffix, you can use:

  element.id.split('_').pop()
- You need to start from the parent table row:

  $(element).closest('tr')
- To select and element with an id starting with a string you can use:

  $('span[id^="tt_"]')

Assembling all the previous points this is my snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  function refreshSums(element) {
    var currentSuffix = element.id.split('_').pop();
    var sp = $('#sp_' + currentSuffix);
    var tt = $('#tt_' + currentSuffix);
    if (!isNaN(element.value) && element.value.length != 0) {
      tt.text(+element.value * +sp.text());
      var total = 0;
      $('span[id^="tt_"]').each(function (index, element) {
        if (!isNaN(element.textContent) && element.textContent.length != 0) {
          total += +element.textContent;
        }
      });
      $('#gotal').text(total);
    } else {
      tt.text('');
      $('#gotal').text('');
    }

  }

  // refresh the sums on document ready
  $('input.form-control.changesNo').on('input', function (e) {
    refreshSums(this);
  });

  // compute the sums on document ready
  $('input.form-control.changesNo').each(function (index, element) {
    refreshSums(element);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control changesNo" id="id_1" name="quantity" value=""></td>
        <td><span id="sp_1">200</span></td>
        <td><span id="tt_1"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control changesNo" id="id_2" name="quantity" value=""></td>
        <td><span id="sp_2">200</span></td>
        <td><span id="tt_2"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control changesNo" id="id_3" name="quantity" value=""></td>
        <td><span id="sp_3">200</span></td>
        <td><span id="tt_3"></span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<span id="gotal"></span>
```

Comment: @Dasans Did you test it using my snippet? Which are the errors? Did you include jQuery library? Let me know